# If one of two elements exists, do something

Tags: jquery, exists

I currently do this to check if one of two elements exists:

```
if ($(".element1").length > 0 || $(".element2").length > 0) {
  //do stuff...
}
```

Is there a better way to rewrite the same? I mean, is `.length` the same as `.length > 0`?

Comment: You might find this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery) answers your question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
if ( $('#myDiv')[0] ) { //do something }
```

..works best!

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery).

Answer (score 48):

```
if ($(".element1").is('*') || $(".element2").is('*')) {
    // code
}
```

**EDIT** (per comment) *Select elements by multiple classes in one call:*

```
if ($(".element1, .element2").is('*')) {
    // code
}
```

Comment: Note that you can also combine the two selectors into one like so: `$(".element1, .element2")`.

Comment: Is ".is()" the same as ".length > 0"? Whats the difference, if any?

Comment: Nimbuz, good post on use of .is() - http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1725-jQuery-s-is-Method-Checks-For-Any-Matching-Elements.htm

Comment: The SO Question Vincent linked to covers the topic thoroughly - good read.

Answer (score 16):

All jQuery elements have the `.length` property. You can just go:

```
if ($('img').length) // Implies: If this element exists..
```

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/element-exists/

Answer (score 2):

```
!$.isEmptyObject($.find('#urId'))
```

this will return "true" if the element exists and False if not

cheers
:)

Answer (score 1):

---

[See Extremely updated version of this plugin **here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery#answer-13313296)! Now uses callback function so you can maintain chainability if you choose. Can completely replace *if statement* or can still be used within *if statement*

---

You could create a very simple jQuery plug-in for this, as such:

## jsFiddle

```
(function($) {
    if (!$.exist) {
        $.extend({
            exist: function(elm) {
                if (typeof elm == null) return false;
                if (typeof elm != "object") elm = $(elm);
                return elm.length ? true : false;
            }
        });
        $.fn.extend({
            exist: function() {
                return $.exist($(this));
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

> **USE**

```
//  With ID 
$.exist("#eleID");
//  OR
$("#eleID").exist();

//  With class name
$.exist(".class-name");
//  OR
$(".class-name").exist();

//  With just tag // prolly not best idea aS there will be other tags on site
$.exist("div");
//  OR
$("div").exist();
```

> With your If statement

```
if ($(".element1").exist() || $(".element2").exist()) {
    ...stuff...
}
```

Of course this plugin could be further extended to be much more fancy (handling multiple calls at once, creating non-existing elements based on a pram), but as it stand now, it does a very simple, very needed function ... Does this element exist? return `True` or `False`

## jsFiddle

Answer (score 1):

Just use .each().

```
$(".element1").each(function(){
  //Do Something here
}
```

Simple...

Answer (score 1):

```
$.fn.exists = function(ifExists) {
    return this.length ? ifExists.call(this, this) : this;
};
```

usage:

```
$('.element1, .element2').exists(function(els) {
    // this and els refers to $('.element1, .element2')
});
```